# Flutter: IgnorePointer not working on children of GestureDetector

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a popup with a form that can submit details with a button.

The 'barrierDissmissable' proprty of the show dialog function no longer works when i use a "SingleChildScrollView" in my Diolog. I assume it is covering it somehow. I used "SingleChildScrollView" to maintain the shape of the dialog when the keyboard appears.

So i wrapped my widget in a gesture detector which pops the context and this is correctly simulating the barrierDissmissable property being true.

Now the problem is whenever i click on any part of the Dialog apart from the TextFormFields or the Button the Diolog dismisses. I tried wrapping it in an IgnorePointer Widget but it did not work properly.

```
  static dynamic showDeleteUserPopup(BuildContext context)async{
    return await showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => DeleteUserDiolog());
}
```

```
class _DeleteUserDiologState extends State<DeleteUserDiolog> {

    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final _email = TextEditingController();
    final _password = TextEditingController();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new  GestureDetector( onTapDown: (tapdownDetails) => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child :  Dialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))),
                child:   Center(
                    child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),

                    child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Text( "Delete your account", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,)),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Text( "Confirm your details below to delete your account", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle.apply(), textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
                        Form(
                            key:_formKey,
                            child: Column(
                                children: [
                                    Container(
                                        width: 300,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child:TextFormField(
                                            controller: _email,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                                            key: Key('email'),
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,)),
                                    Container(
                                        width: 300,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child: TextFormField(
                                            controller: _password,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                                            key: Key('password'),
                                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                            obscureText: true,)),
                                ]
                            )
                        ),
                        CupertinoDialogAction(
                            isDestructiveAction: true,
                            child: Text('Delete', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3.apply(color: Colors.red),),
                            onPressed: () => Dbf.deleteCurrectUser(_email.text, _password.text).then((_){
                                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));
                            }).catchError((e){
                                PopUps.showAlert('Error', "The credentials were wrong.", "OK", () => Navigator.pop(context), context);
                            }),
                        )
                    ],
                )
                )
            )
        )
        )
        );
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click on the dark overly to dismiss the popup. This stops working when i wrap the Dialog in a "SingleChildScrollView" but i need to do this so the popup maintains it's shape when the keyboard appears.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try `showDialog()` call?

Comment: Yeah thats how i'm creating the popup but it doesn't dismiss even with the 'barrier dismissible' attribute set to true. Thats why i have to wrap it in a gesture detector at the moment. See above as I added the showDialog code.